# Trying to make the discord.js-musicbot-addon work. When music is about to play i get this error

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined
at C:\Users\pink\Desktop\IwtdB0t_v.7\node_modules\discord.js-musicbot-addon\index.js:1474:41
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I've tried to update every discord.js v11 command to discord.js v12 but  error still appears after changing from playStream to play. Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with the discord.js-musicbot-addon library, so there's unfortunately not much you can do.

[The code I think is causing the error](https://github.com/DarkoPendragon/discord.js-musicbot-addon/blob/master/index.js#L1408-L1474) (some irrelevant code removed, indentation removed and comments added for readability):

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const voiceConnection = client.voice.connections.find(val => val.channel.guild.id == msg.guild.id);

  // This line here is what (I believe) is ultimately causing the error.
  // Collection#find returns undefined, not null, when an item cannot be found.
  // Because this uses strict equality (===), an undefined voiceConnection (e.g.
  // the bot hasn't connected to a voice channel yet) won't trigger this code.
  if (voiceConnection === null) {
    // attempts to connect to the voice channel
    /* ... */
  } else {
    // The promise is resolved with a potentially undefined voiceConnection.
    resolve(voiceConnection);
  }
}).then(connection => {
  // retrieves the video to play
  /* ... */

  try {
    /* ... */

    // This line is where the error is. When connection is undefined, it throws
    // the error "Cannot read property 'play' of undefined"
    let dispatcher = connection.play(ytdl(video.url, {
      filter: 'audioonly',
      quality: 'highestaudio'
    }), {
      bitrate: mjusicbot.bitRate,
      volume: (queue.volume / 100)
    })
```

Note that discord.js-musicbot-addon is deprecated on NPM and is no longer supported. From [the repo](https://github.com/DarkoPendragon/discord.js-musicbot-addon):

> This project is NO LONGER SUPPORTED and does NOT function. Do not use this.